# Using SSE to round in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, sse, rounding, inline-assembly

I wrote this function to round singles to integers:

```
function Round(const Val: Single): Integer;
begin
  asm
    cvtss2si eax,Val
    mov Result,eax
  end;
end;
```

It works, but I need to change the rounding mode. Apparently, per [this](http://softpixel.com/~cwright/programming/simd/sse.php), I need to set the MXCSR register.

How do I do this in Delphi?

The reason I am doing this in the first place is I need "away-from-zero" rounding (like in C#), which is not possible even via SetRoundingMode.

Comment: You don't need `mov Result, eax`. Result **is** eax. Actually `function Round(const Val: Single): Integer;
asm
  cvtss2si eax,Val
end;` is enough ;)

Comment: Thanks. That answers another question.

Comment: @BBaz, how come I can't do the same on this function: function MSb(const Val: Integer): Integer;
begin
  if Val = 0 then
    Result := -1
  else asm
    BSR       EAX, Val
    MOV       Result, EAX
  end;
end;

Comment: Because in my previous comment it's an (almost) **naked** asm function. You have to write the branch (if then else) in asm too. Note that I forgot the RET...to make it a true naked asm funct.

Comment: Thank you. Someone helped me to figure it out (including getting past what seems to be a compiler error): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27133303/delphi-assembler-understanding-the-result-register/27133568?noredirect=1#comment42766381_27133568

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On modern Delphi, to set MXCSR you can call [`SetMXCSR`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SetMXCSR) from the `System` unit. To read the current value use [`GetMXCSR`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.GetMXCSR).

Do beware that `SetMXCSR`, just like `Set8087CW` is not thread-safe. Despite my efforts to persuade Embarcadero to change this, it seems that this particular design flaw will remain with us forever.

On older versions of Delphi you use the `LDMXCSR` and `STMXCSR` opcodes. You might write your own versions like this:

```
function GetMXCSR: LongWord;
asm
  PUSH    EAX
  STMXCSR [ESP].DWord
  POP     EAX
end;

procedure SetMXCSR(NewMXCSR: LongWord);
//thread-safe version that does not abuse the global variable DefaultMXCSR
var
  MXCSR: LongWord;
asm
  AND     EAX, $FFC0 // Remove flag bits
  MOV     MXCSR, EAX
  LDMXCSR MXCSR
end;
```

These versions are thread-safe and I hope will compile and work on older Delphi versions.

Do note that using the name `Round` for your function is likely to cause a lot of confusion. I would advise that you do not do that.

Finally, I checked in the Intel documentation and both of the Intel floating point units (x87, SSE) offer just the rounding modes specified by the IEEE754 standard. They are:

- Round to nearest (even)
- Round down (toward −∞)
- Round up (toward +∞)
- Round toward zero (Truncate)

So, your desired rounding mode is not available.

Comment: Thank you. I internally called it "TrueRound". What you wrote is similar to what I already have. I'm hoping to use SSE for this.

Comment: I've adapted my threadsafe version of `SetMXCSR` so that I think it will work in D7. I don't have D7 at hand. The code in the Q compiles in D6. So you should be good to go.

Comment: You're a mind reader. You added the next function I needed. Thanks so much :)

Comment: Suppose some other code processed by this thread relies on another rounding mode. Does it not quickly get messy setting the mode? Just read an article, [Floating-Point Determinism](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/floating-point-determinism/).

Comment: @LURD Presumably the code that IanC will implement will save away MXCSR, make a change to it, round, and then restore MXCSR

Comment: I sure hope so, but I have seen implementations not doing so. Not fun at all.

Comment: @LURD Even when you try to be a good citizen and do that you can be caught out by the appalling implementation of `Set8087CW` and `SetMXCSR` which have the ability to inject control words from one thread into another.

Comment: As a side note, Trunc is considerably faster than Floor. I discovered that AwayFromZero is not possible with SSE, but setting the flag's bits 13 & 14 does at least result in a more even pattern.

Comment: @IanC Trunc would be even faster if the implementation didn't make such a meal of the control word.

Comment: I'm deducing that C#'s MidPointRounding.AwayFromZero is contrived. It's a little shocking that Intel CPUs have no such rounding mode.

Comment: That is correct, up to a point. I added some more text. There is indeed no away from zero rounding mode, but then Intel are simply following IEEE754 which does not define such a mode. So I don't see it as particularly shocking.

Comment: Although it's also worth pointing out that ieee754 was based on the Intel 8087 coprocessor so we have a chicken and egg situation!