# Delphi assembler: understanding the Result register

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, inline-assembly, basm

I'm messing around with ASM in Delphi. From my understanding, EAX holds Result. In the following, I have to put RET at the end, otherwise Result is not correct (it is correct if the input is 0). What am I doing wrong, or should I say, what don't I understand about this?

```
function MSb(const Val: Integer): Integer;
label
  Go;
asm
  CMP       EAX, 0
  JNZ       Go
  MOV       EAX, -1
  RET
Go:
  BSR       EBX, EAX
  MOV       EAX, EBX
  RET
end;
```

If I say the following:

```
  MOV       Result, EBX
```

Then I get the following compilation:

```
  MOV [EPB-$04], EBX
  MOV EAX, [EPB-$04]
```

However, my code above has the following postscript:

```
  MOV       EAX, EDX
  RET
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least without optimization enabled, your function has a pre-amble and a post-amble. Have a look at it:

```
Project46.dpr.13: asm
0041A1F4 55               push ebp
0041A1F5 8BEC             mov ebp,esp
0041A1F7 83C4F8           add esp,-$08
0041A1FA 8945F8           mov [ebp-$08],eax
Project46.dpr.14: CMP       EAX, 0
0041A1FD 83F800           cmp eax,$00
Project46.dpr.15: JNZ       Go
0041A200 7506             jnz $0041a208
Project46.dpr.16: MOV       EAX, -1
0041A202 B8FFFFFFFF       mov eax,$ffffffff
Project46.dpr.17: RET
0041A207 C3               ret 
Project46.dpr.19: BSR       EBX, EAX
0041A208 0FBDD8           bsr ebx,eax
Project46.dpr.20: MOV       EAX, EBX
0041A20B 89D8             mov eax,ebx
Project46.dpr.21: RET
0041A20D C3               ret 
Project46.dpr.22: end;
0041A20E 8B45FC           mov eax,[ebp-$04]
0041A211 59               pop ecx
0041A212 59               pop ecx
0041A213 5D               pop ebp
0041A214 C3               ret
```

So the pre-amble sets up the stack frame. It saves away the `ebp` register, and modifies both the `ebp` and `esp` registers. Notice also the post-amble. You do need to execute that code to restore the saved registers.

The usual way to deal with this is to jump to the end of the function instead of using `ret`. So write your code like this:

```
function MSb(const Val: Integer): Integer;
asm
  CMP       EAX, 0
  JNZ       @@go
  MOV       EAX, -1
  JMP       @@exit
@@go:
  BSR       EBX, EAX
  MOV       EAX, EBX
@@exit:
end;
```

This way you ensure that the post-amble is executed. You really should get into the habit of writing the code this way to ensure that any pre-amble is executed.

---

Now, beyond that I suspect that the problem you mention in the question actually relates to a compiler bug relating to your use of a Pascal label rather than an asm label. Well, perhaps it is a compiler bug, but perhaps it is just a mistake to use a Pascal label. Consider the following program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

function MSb(const Val: Integer): Integer;
asm
  CMP       EAX, 0
  JNZ       @@Go
  MOV       EAX, -1
  JMP       @@exit
@@Go:
  BSR       EBX, EAX
  MOV       EAX, EBX
@@exit:
end;

function MSb2(const Val: Integer): Integer;
label
  Go;
asm
  CMP       EAX, 0
  JNZ       Go
  MOV       EAX, -1
  RET
Go:
  BSR       EBX, EAX
  MOV       EAX, EBX
end;

begin
  Writeln(Msb(0));
  Writeln(Msb(1));
  Writeln(Msb2(0));
  Writeln(Msb2(1));
  Readln;
end.
```

The output when compiled with optimization is:

```
-1
0
-1
4
```

So, what about that rather odd `4`. Well, let's look at the assembled code for `Msb2`, which is essentially your code:

```
004059E8 83F800           cmp eax,$00
004059EB 7506             jnz $004059f3
004059ED B8FFFFFFFF       mov eax,$ffffffff
004059F2 C3               ret 
004059F3 0FBDD8           bsr ebx,eax
004059F6 89D8             mov eax,ebx
004059F8 8BC2             mov eax,edx
004059FA C3               ret
```

Why on earth is the value of `edx`, a volatile register whose value has not been assigned, being moved into `eax` just before the function returns. This is the problem that you are reporting. My guess is that the use of a Pascal label is confusing the assembler. Stick to asm labels.

Here is the assembled code for `Msb`:

```
004059D4 83F800           cmp eax,$00
004059D7 7506             jnz $004059df
004059D9 B8FFFFFFFF       mov eax,$ffffffff
004059DE C3               ret 
004059DF 0FBDD8           bsr ebx,eax
004059E2 89D8             mov eax,ebx
004059E4 C3               ret
```

That's more like it! Notice how the compiler knows that there is no post-able here, and replaces the `jmp @@exit` with a straight `ret`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65677/discussion-on-answer-by-david-heffernan-delphi-assembler-understanding-the-resu).

Comment: @Flexo Thanks. My take is that the comment thread here was fine and useful and informative.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong, or should I say, what don't I understand about
>   this?

Basically as clearly stated the pre and post-ambles but also be careful when using assembler code. Parameters are passed in different ways depending upon calling conventions. Your code will run fine with the `Pascal` (ironically obsolete) calling convention, if you remove the `label`, the `RET` and use assembler labels (`@@`). It is good practice to always indicate a calling convention for assembly code, since `Result` may refer indeed to `EAX` or a *local* variable for holding it. `EAX` maps directly to `Result` when using the `Register` (default) calling convention.